# I have succeeded in connecting apache to tomcat using mod_jk but jsp are not executed rather they are shown as plain text files

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat, mod-jk

I have followed the instructions on this link 
http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-connect-apache-to-tomcat-using-the-mod-jk-module.html?page=1
to connect apache to tomcat and i am able to call a jsp page from apache via mod_jk. However the jsp is shown as plain text file when i issue the following url http://localhost/alg3eng/index.jsp. When i call http://localhost:8085/alg3eng/index.jsp, the page is rendered correctly. Where am doing it wrong?

I added the following in **httpd.conf**

```
LoadModule jk_module C:/Apache24/modules/mod_jk.so

<IfModule jk_module>

    JkWorkersFile C:/Apache24/conf/workers.properties
    JkLogFile C:/Apache24/logs/mod_jk.log
    JkLogStampFormat "[%b %d %Y - %H:%M:%S] "
    JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"
    JkLogLevel info

    JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories

    Alias /alg3eng "C:/tomcat/webapps/alg3eng/"

    <Directory "C:/tomcat/webapps/alg3eng/">
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Location /*/WEB-INF/*>
        Require all denied
    </Location>

    JkMount /alg3eng/*.jsp worker1

</IfModule>
```

and i have my **workers.properties** file as follows:

```
# Define 1 real worker using ajp13
worker.list=worker1
# Set properties for worker1 (ajp13)
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.port=8019
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a little rusty on this, but you may want to remove the Alias and Directory directives and just go with the JKMount directive.

Comment: @PaulNgom: Here's my workers.properties file and httpd.conf file segment.<br/>

Comment: Sorry, my past comment got truncated.@PaulNgom: Here's my httpd.conf file   segment.  <IfModule jk_module>
 JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties  
    JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log  
    JkLogStampFormat "[%b %d %Y - %H:%M:%S] "  
 JkMount /*.jsp ajp13  
   JkMount /examples/* ajp13 
</IfModule>   This allows me to access http:/localhost/examples/